# ConEmu - running a script in the startup console

Tags: shell-script, conemu

I have a script called `todo` that echoes a todo list to the terminal. I'd like ConEmu to run this every time it starts (thus, in the starting tab). How do I write a task to make it do that? `todo` is on my path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, your question does not refer to ConEmu, at all.
Read your shell manual (you have not eve said what of dozen possible shells you are using).
For example, cmd has "/k" switch, PowerShell has "-noexit -command" and so on...

Possibly related:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374719/1405560

Comment: This answer helped me - thanks. A future visitor will probably want to create a profile or some equivalent for their shell. Just adding (one of the many shells), for Windows Powershell 7: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7 .